Adding lambda layers to Amplify gen 2 functions
can someone guide me on how to add an existing lambda layer to a gen 2 amplify function? I couldn't find any reference to do this in their documentation, but I have found some external references that has helped:

https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-backend/issues/1281
https://www.talkncloud.com/lambda-layers-with-aws-cdk/

To clarify, I have an existing lambda layer from a different project that I want to reuse and is already deployed on the console. Now, I just want to attach it to an amplify gen 2 function in backend.ts. However, the examples above are using either a local path to a layer or classes, which I don't think is applicable in my situation. I can't use a local path as the layer code is in a different repo, and I don't know how to use classes in conjunction with AWS amplify's backend code.
Here is how my attempt to add a lambda layer looks like:
import { defineBackend } from '@aws-amplify/backend'
import { auth } from './auth/resource'
import { data } from './data/resource'
import { myFunc} from './functions/MyFunc/resource'
import * as lambda from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-lambda'
import { Stack } from 'aws-cdk-lib'

const backend = defineBackend({
  auth,
  data,
  myFunc,
})

const myFuncLambda = backend.myFunc.resources.lambda as lambda.Function

const layerVersion = lambda.LayerVersion.fromLayerVersionArn(
  Stack.of(myFuncLambda),
  'myFuncLayer',
  'arn:aws:lambda:{AWS::REGION}:{AWS::ACCOUNTID}:layer:{AWS::LAYERNAME}:{AWS::LAYERVERSION}'
)

myFuncLambda.addLayers(layerVersion)

Edit: For further clarification, the code I provided does not work when deploying to amplify. I get this error message when I try to deploy:
NodeJSFunctionConstructInitializationError: Failed to instantiate nodejs function construct


If the code is functioning correctly, there is no issue. This is because Amplify Gen2 is built on the AWS Cloud Development Kit (CDK) framework. Any valid CDK code will work seamlessly with Amplify Gen2.

This is how added lambda layer in my Amplify Gen2 App.
import { defineBackend } from '@aws-amplify/backend';
import { auth } from './auth/resource';
import { data } from './data/resource';
import { storage } from './storage/resource';
import { generateThumbnail } from './functions/generate-thmbnail/resource';
import * as lambda from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-lambda';
import 'dotenv/config'

var sharpLambdaLayerArn = process.env.SHARP_LAMBDA_LAYER_ARN;
var ffmpegLambdaLayerArn = process.env.FFMPEG_LAMBDA_LAYER_ARN;

if (!sharpLambdaLayerArn || !ffmpegLambdaLayerArn) {
  throw new Error('Missing required environment variables');
}

const backend = defineBackend({
  auth,
  data,
  storage,
  generateThumbnail
});


// Add the Sharp Layer to the generateThumbnail function
const generateThumbnailLambda = backend.generateThumbnail.resources.lambda as lambda.Function
const sharpLambdaLayer = lambda.LayerVersion.fromLayerVersionArn(generateThumbnailLambda, "SharpLayer", sharpLambdaLayerArn)
generateThumbnailLambda.addLayers(sharpLambdaLayer)

